# Discord.py Mock command

Tags: python, discord.py

Im Trying to make a Mock command. Like a user can type "!mock hello you." And the bot should output "HeLlO yOu."
I dont have a Plan how to do that maybe you can help me :D

```
    @bot.command()
    async def mock(ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.send("Here should the bot send the mocked message")
```

Comment: Do you have any working code so far? Show us what you've attempted.

Comment: Do you know how to write a Discord bot command at all? Do you know how to take in the input text and create the desired output text? What happened when you tried to write the code?

Comment: Yes, i have a start. wait a min please i gonna edit the message

Answer (score 0):

Using the random module and assuming you're passing the whole message in the correct way:

```
@bot.command()
async def mock(ctx, *, message):
    out = ''.join(random.choice((str.upper, str.lower))(c) for c in message)
    await ctx.send(out)
```

Comment: Thanks, but its like Randomizing the Capital letters, it should do it like "ThIs Is A mOcKeD mEsSaGe" and not like "ThiS iS a MocKed mESSage", i'l hope you can Fix it! Thanks for Helping :DDDD